# How to access object data and display the comments

Tags: php, loops, object

How do I access the comments and display them?

```
stdClass Object
(
[stream] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 521734635_403433313001586
        [from] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Jonathan Rosario
                [id] => 521734635
            )

        [message] => What if we do the same action in our country?...i just hope they be fair. Its just unfair that they also ban our Bibles while we never ban their Qu'rans in our country.
        [comments] => stdClass Object
            (
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 521734635_403433313001586_90696065
                                [from] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [name] => ''
                                        [id] => 570761262
                                    )

                                [message] => test
                                [created_time] => 2012-03-29T10:01:49+0000
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 521734635_403433313001586_90696070
                                [from] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [name] => Alwaynne Kevin
                                        [id] => 100000364267158
                                    )

                                [message] => Oo nga...bakit ganyan sila...hahah.!
                                [created_time] => 2012-03-29T10:07:52+0000
                            )

                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 521734635_403433313001586_90696146
                                [from] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [name] => Jp Peña
                                        [id] => 100000599584313
                                    )

                                [message] => they're just doing what the "christian" crusaders did to them.
                                [created_time] => 2012-03-29T10:33:12+0000
                            )

                    )

                [count] => 3
            )

        [picture] => http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCr7a57qDUU2MHR&w=90&h=90&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.interaksyon.com%2Fassets%2Fimages%2Farticles%2Finterphoto_1332546902.jpg
        [name] => Top Saudi cleric 'issues fatwa' on Christian churches; Bishops alarmed - InterAksyon.com
        [description] => Christian bishops are sharply criticizing Saudi Arabia's top religious official after reports that he issued a fatwa saying all churches on the Arabian Peninsula should be destroyed. At least 3.5 million Christians live in the Gulf Arab region. They are mostly Catholic workers from the Philippines a...
        [created_time] => 2012-03-29T10:00:41+0000
    )

)
```

Comment: That's a data structure. You do not "parse" data structures. You already have them in memory. And you just need to "traverse" or "access" the values. And it's not quite clear why that would pose a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you got the whole list of objects in comments so give try following:

```
foreach( $yourObj->stream->comments as $comment){
   echo sprintf('%s: %s', $comment->from->name, $comment->message);
}
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.